# C++ Composition program error(xcor undeclared )

Tags: c++

Error!xcor undeclared at setAll() function

I had created object of  PointType in Circle class to do sort of composition, but at the initialization of the constructor of Circle it is showing that

" [Error] 'ycor' was not declared in this scope "

" [Error] 'xcor' was not declared in this scope "

I want xcor and ycor in my Circle class in order to get the Radius using setAll() function

Please help!at what i am messing up.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class PointType{

    private:

    int xcor;//x coordinate
    int ycor;//y coordinate
    public:

    PointType();//constructor
    PointType(int x,int y);
    void setPoint(int x,int y);
    int getx() const;
    int gety() const;


};  
PointType::PointType():xcor(0),ycor(0)
{

}   

PointType::PointType(int x,int y):xcor(x),ycor(y){
}

void PointType::setPoint(int x,int y){
    xcor=x;
    ycor=y;

}

int PointType::getx() const{
    return xcor;
    }


int PointType::gety() const{
    return ycor;
    }

class Circle{

    protected:
        float Radius;
        float Area;
        int Circumference;
        float pi;
        PointType obj1;

    public:

    Circle();
    void setAll();
    float getRadius();

    float getArea();


    float getCircumference();
    void callFunction();
    void printAll();
    void pt(int x,int y);


};  

Circle::Circle():Radius(0),Area(0),Circumference(0),pi(3.1415),obj1(xcor,ycor){
}

void Circle::setAll(){

        Radius=sqrt(  (xcor*xcor)  + (ycor*ycor)  );
        Area=pi*Radius*Radius;
        Circumference=2*pi*Radius;
}

float Circle::getRadius(){
    return Radius;
}

float Circle::getArea(){
    return Area;
}

float Circle::getCircumference(){
    return Circumference;
}

void Circle::printAll(){

        cout<<"The Area is :"<<Area<<endl;
        cout<<"The Circumference is :"<<Circumference<<endl;    
    }
void Circle::pt(int x,int y){
    obj1.setPoint(x,y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Circle` doesn't have any member variable called `xcor` or `ycor`. If you want to get the values of your `PointType` object, your `setAll` function should look like:

```
Radius=sqrt(  (obj1.getx()*obj1.getx())  + (obj1.gety()*obj1.gety())  );
```

Also you have to change your constructor:

```
Circle::Circle():Radius(0),Area(0),Circumference(0),pi(3.1415),obj1(0,0)
```

as it doesn't have access to any `xcor` or `ycor` either.

Answer (score 0):

declare xcor,ycor to Circle' constructor argument, and

add this line before computing Radius:

```
int xcor = obj1.getx(), ycor = obj1.gety();
Radius=sqrt(  (xcor*xcor)  + (ycor*ycor)  );
```

You could also consider to inherit PointType for Circle, instead of embedded obj1:

```
class Circle : public PointType
{
public: Circle(int x, int y):PointType(x, y) {}
...
/* remove obj1 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to change your Circle constructor, because it knows nothing about xcor and ycor:

   `Circle::Circle():Radius(0),Area(0),Circumference(0),pi(3.1415),obj1(42,56)`
2. The Circle class still doesn't know about xcor and ycor, so you have to change setAll method:

   `Radius=sqrt(  static_cast<double>((obj1.getx()*obj1.getx())  + (obj1.gety()*obj1.gety()))  );`